Creating a live video stream server that mimics a static MP4 file?
I'm trying to make Airplay work on Linux for screen mirroring. pyatv has been great for displaying static content (mp4/audio) but it cannot deal with live video streams.
To play a video via Airplay, you pass in a URL (http[s]) which the client (AppleTV or Macbook in this case) fetches and plays.
Illustration of the requests
My idea is that since I can control the server from which the MP4 is served, I can fake metadata to tell the client that the video is extremely long (like 24 hours) and stream in my screen capture as it goes. The client can control seeking & playback so I'll need to handle that as well (sending the same stream but with different timestamps?).
So my question is
a. Is that plausible?
b. How would I go about writing such a server? (Well, I can already pipe in data from wf-recorder → ffmpeg (for mp4 conversion) → stdout). I think the difficulty would be handling the mp4 file format & handling seek etc. Are there any easily available libraries? (preferably Golang but Python works as well.)
Alternative solutions considered:
while True:
    # TODO: Wait for lock to prevent read/write race
    await airplay.stream.play_url("/path/to/file")

Screen record for five seconds and change the file. When it finishes playing, it will fetch the file again with the new data. Downside is that there will be gaps where the screen turns black while it waits for the new file to load. You can't schedule it.
